# rails g scaffold series name:string - is this a naming convention error or something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, series, scaffold

On my blog I'm have posts that belong to a series. I've tried to scaffold series but there are some problems with routes.

The pluralization engine doesn't get it right so I had to manually change `Sery`, `@series`, and `@sery` which is not a big deal.

The routing seems to be ok with `resources :series`. But then when I try to create a series the `form_for` helper complains about the route.

And then when I create it with console it works but rails is still complaining about routes.

Please create a simple app and see what the problem is.

```
rails new test_series_app
```

And then run the scaffold generator:

```
rails g scaffold series name:string
```

And see how the routes are getting mixed up and help me out please!

Comment: Which version of rails? As everything works on 3.1 RC?

Comment: also if you need to adjust the pluralization, check out config/initializers/inflections.rb

Comment: Rails 3. How did you treat the singular and plural forms of series.

Comment: I used Sery, series, and sery.

Comment: I'm assuming like  Mikhail-Nikalyukin you did Series, serie, and series

Comment: All I did was scaffold series, and the generated code works fine for me (on Rails 3.x (both 3.0.9 and 3.1rc4). It just uses series for everything. and the form_for(@series)  works fine.  If you change it to be Sery,@series, @sery... did you change the inflector to know about your change.

Comment: @Codeglot let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1266/discussion-between-doon-and-sam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I put the singularize code into the scaffold generator (yes, my one contribution to Rails).  All it does is check if `record_name == record_name.pluralize`.  If it does and you haven't passed in `--force-plural`, it calls `record_name = record_name.singularize`.

In this case "series".pluralize is the same as "series".singularize so I assume it won't do anything.

So if you're having problems w/ it, you need to write an inflector for the word.

(I wrote it after Jeremy Kemper's 2008 RailsConf keynote in which he accidentally passed in a plural model name causing himself all sorts of grief in the middle of his talk.)